# obtain disk serial number from drive letter

Tags: powershell

I would like to get the serial number, as in the serial number returned from the PowerShell Get-Disk cmdlet, associated with the drive letter of a windows volume. I'm strugling to find anything that will point me in the correct direction for how to do this. I can see that people have managed to do this on site this via WMI queries invoked from vbscript and c#, e.g.

```
private string GetDiskIndex(string driveLetter)
    {
        driveLetter = driveLetter.TrimEnd('\\');

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\root\cimv2");
        var drives = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_DiskDrive")).Get();
        foreach(var drive in drives)
        {

            var partitions = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + drive["DeviceID"] + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition")).Get();
            foreach(var partition in partitions)
            {
                var logicalDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + partition["DeviceID"] + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition")).Get();
                foreach (var logicalDisk in logicalDisks)
                {
                    if (logicalDisk["DeviceId"].ToString() == driveLetter) return partition["DiskIndex"].ToString();
                }
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this in PowerShell ?

Answer (score 7):

The WMI/CIM stuff could be done with powershell too. But you can also do:

```
get-partition -DriveLetter C | get-disk
```

Comment: `Get-Disk` is not available to Windows 7 as an FYI.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple to duplicate your code with the CIM cmdlets:

```
$DriveLetter = 'C:'

Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DiskDrive |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition |
    Where-Object DeviceId -eq $DriveLetter |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition |
    Select-Object -Property DiskIndex
```

If you just want the base unsigned integer value of `DiskIndex`, use `-ExpandProperty DiskIndex` instead.

This is useful if your version of Windows doesn't have `Get-Partition` or `Get-Drive`, but you do have PowerShell v3.0+.

Your code says you want the `DiskIndex`, which is what the above code does.  However, your question says you want the `SerialNumber`.  Here's how to get that:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DiskDrive |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition |
    Where-Object DeviceId -eq $DriveLetter |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition |
    Select-Object -Property SerialNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$drive_serialnumber = Get-Partition -DriveLetter C  | Get-Disk | select-object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
$drive_serialnumber.trim()
```

Use trim to remove the blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of all available drives

```
$d = (Get-PSDrive).Name -match '^[a-z]$'
```

For each of the drivers, extract the serial number

```
get-partition -DriveLetter $i | get-disk
```

Complete working code

```
$d = (Get-PSDrive).Name -match '^[a-z]$'
Foreach ($i in $d)
{
  Write-Host $i". " -nonewline
  get-partition -DriveLetter $i | get-disk 
}
```

Ouput

> E. 0      WDC WDS240G2XXX-00JHXX    19377B803XXX     Healthy              Online       223.57 GB GPT
> F. 13     Seagate Backup+ Hub BK    NXXQWHXX         Healthy              Online         7.28 TB GPT
> G. 12     Seagate Backup+ Hub BK    NAXX58XX         Healthy              Online         7.28 TB GPT